# exporting and uploading mysql database from dev to production

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of implementing an upgrade to my small website that consists mainly of adding 13 tables to my mysql database, loading a few rows into each (type codes and reference data).   I was able to do a release previously when I created the database in production and populated it with one table.

I created that one by hand via the php mysql admin tool (shared hosting at godaddy), and I guess I can do the same thing again since my release is still small.  But, I'd like to know what some of the best ways to upload the database to production would be.  I'd like to be able to take a snapshot of the database tables along w/ the contents of some of the reference tables and ftp them to production and load them.  And, I'd like to know what is best to use for more complicated sites (which my site is going to be over time) and accounts for any procedures or triggers (which I don't have yet).

Since my site is live, i don't want to figure this out with trial and error while it's down, so . your suggestions are appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [pictured tutorial](http://www.viiratech.com/tutorials/software/exporting-mysql-database-with-phpmyadmin.html) of how you can do this using phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what are you looking for is dump import-export function. Phpmyadmin allows to do this by clicking few buttons.

Comment: OK - thanks.  Thats what I thought, and I guess what I need to do is just create a 2nd DB in test and build/test the scripts against that DB to ensure they work, and then migrate them to production while changing whatever name/etc. needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Most hosting companies provide an interface for you to execute SQL scripts against your database. You can write a script that creates your the tables and inserts data into them.